# Accordion on scroll using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm working with accordion tabs. On click is working fine. Now I want to add some more functionality to it. I want on scroll these tabs should be open/change after completion of all five tabs, then move to the next section using jQuery. I tried using scrollTo but didn't achieve it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("ul#tabs li").click(function(e) {
    var tabIndex = $(this).index();
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      var nthChild = tabIndex + 1;
      $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#content-tab div.active").removeClass("active");
      $("#content-tab div:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $("#content-tab div.active").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#tabs {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#tabs li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 2px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #252525;
  border-bottom: solid 2px grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul#tabs li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

ul#tabs li.active {
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

ul#tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content-tab div {
  display: none;
}

#content-tab div.active {
  display: block;
}

#content-tab>div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00618c;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="content-tab">
    <div class="active">Convallis quis nulla pharetra, tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
    <div>retra, tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
    <div>is quis nulla pharetra, tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
    <div>s nulla pharetra, tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
    <div>tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: To clarify, after I've clicked on each one of the tabs I should show all the tab information. Next, you want me to scroll to the gray area. Correct?

Comment: I updated my solution based on your comments.

Comment: If you accordion has enough content then you change tab on scroll easily. means each tab should have enough content to cover the current view port area so that to view next tab user need to scroll down.

Comment: @ Rajesh Kumar yes, we can do by giving the specific width to all div's.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your new comments I think I understand. what you need to do is check on scroll if the scroll position is greater than the height of the wrapper div. If so, then change classes to active. See below:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
```

....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#tabs li").click(function(e) {
    var tabIndex = $(this).index();
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      var nthChild = tabIndex + 1;
      $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#content-tab div.active").removeClass("active");
      $("#content-tab div:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $("#content-tab div.active").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var bodyRect = window.document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    var wrapperRect = window.document.getElementById("wrapper").getBoundingClientRect();
    var bodyScrollPos = (bodyRect.top * -1);

    if(bodyScrollPos >= wrapperRect.height) {
        $("#content-tab>div").addClass("active");
      $("ul#tabs li").addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/nzc4jq29/18/)

Comment: No, my question is like onClick classes are changing like this onScroll also classes should change.

Comment: Ok but how should the classes change onscroll? Can you clarify this part "I want on scroll these tabs should be open/change after completion of all five tabs"?

Comment: little bit you confuse.onscroll to this section at a time one div will be displayed as I did in onclick. Same functionality what I did but I want to add some more feature onscroll.Not like this after scroll, all div should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your JS functionality : After All tabs have been open completed then move to the next section

**Solutions :**

additional class `view-complete` included in `active` Tab list in HTML

`<li class="active view-complete"></li>` to verified open tab view is completed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tabs li").on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            return false;
        }

        $("#tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active view-complete");

        var nthChild = $(this).index() + 1;

        $("#content-tab div").removeClass("active");
        $("#content-tab div:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").addClass("active");

        if ($("#tabs li").length === $('.view-complete').length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".block").offset().top
            }, 1000, function() {
               console.log('You have open all tabs completed - !done');
               $("#tabs li").removeClass("view-complete");
               $("#tabs li:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").addClass("view-complete");
            });
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#tabs {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#tabs li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 2px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #252525;
  border-bottom: solid 2px grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul#tabs li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

ul#tabs li.active {
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

ul#tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content-tab div {
  display: none;
}

#content-tab div.active {
  display: block;
}

#content-tab>div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00618c;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active view-complete"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="content-tab">
    <div class="active">Convallis quis nulla pharetra, tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
    <div>retra, tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
    <div>is quis nulla pharetra, tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
    <div>s nulla pharetra, tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
    <div>tempor molestie metus. Nunc ultrices sapien eget scelerisque vestibulum. Tempor turpis sed tellus sit amet condimentum sem.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

its Helpful :)

Comment: .my question is when we on this section on mouse scroll also change class like onclick how it is working.